# Create a Html LI Element with TextNode in a single line, and put them on the UL element

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, var

This code isn't working appropriately:

```
let ulElement = document.createElement('ul');
function create() {
    for (name of names) {
        ulElement.appendChild(document.createElement('li').appendChild(document.createTextNode(name)))
    }
    document.querySelector('#container').appendChild(ulElement)
}
```

This is the generated HTML code:

```
<ul>
    "Diego"
    "Gabriel"
    "Lucas"
</ul>
```

Althought multiple lines (like down) working, I would like to know if is possible to generate in a single line.

```
function createLI() {
    for (name of names) {
        var li = document.createElement('li')
        var textNode = document.createTextNode(name)
        li.appendChild(textNode)
        ulElement.appendChild(li)
    }
    document.querySelector('#container').appendChild(ulElement)
}
```

My first post here, sorry for something. =)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.map()` and **template literals**.

```js
people = ["Diego","Gabriel","Lucas"];

function createList(names) {
    document.querySelector('#container').innerHTML = `<ul>${people.map((name) => `<li>I am ${name}.</li>`).join('')}</ul>`;
}

createList(people);
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's it! Thank you! =)
Not like I thought, without innerHTML, but useful.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow! 
If this answer - or any other one that follows - solved your issue, please consider to mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older questions which still do not have answers.